# Compare integer in attribute source

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a left arrow that when clicked should decrement the filename so that the previous picture is loaded.

I thought using parseint with a radix would do it (commented out) but in case it turned out to be NAN I used string replace, but it still doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

```
$('#lar').on("click", function() {
    /*var num = parseInt( $('#main-img').attr('src'),  10);
    if (num > 0) {*/

    var num = $('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+/, '');

    if (num > 0) {
        $('#main-img').attr('src', $('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(val) {
            return parseInt(val) - 1;
        }));
    }
});
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

1. Your `regex` is incorrect
2. You need to cast the extracted string to `numbers`.

You are not extracting the numbers using the `regex`. Use following `regex` to extract the numbers from string.

```
var num = $('#main-img').attr('src').match(/(\d+)/)[1];
```

You need to parse the string to integer using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Otherwise, the condition `num > 0` will never be satisfied.

```
var num = parseInt($('#main-img').attr('src').match(/(\d+)/)[1], 10);
//        ^^^^^^^^^                                             ^^^^^
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = 'abc123';

var num = str.match(/(\d+)/)[1];

document.write('num= ' + num);
document.write('<br />');
document.write('<br />');
document.write(typeof num);
document.write('<br />');
document.write(typeof parseInt(num, 10));
```

Comment: Why Downvote? Please add comment here. Can something be improved?

Comment: Thank you tushar (and everyone else for also answering) I was considering using match. I'm going to blame my morning brain. This works perfectly.